# Criando o proprio Snippet no Atom

Tags: editor-de-texto, atom

Estou tentando criar meus proprios snippets no atom, porem nenhum deles tem qualquer funcionamento.

tentei:

```
'*':
  'Controller text'
    'prefix': 'lco'
    'body': 'my name is $1'
```

porem ao digitar `lco` e apertar TAB, não faz nada, também tentei para php

```
'.source.php':
  'Controller text'
    'prefix': 'lco'
    'body': 'my name is $1'
```

e para html

```
'.source.html':
  'Controller text'
    'prefix': 'lco'
    'body': 'my name is $1'
```

ou

```
'.text.html':
  'Controller text'
    'prefix': 'lco'
    'body': 'my name is $1'
```

Em nenhuma das formas que crio meus snippets pessoais o Atom cria os snippets. Nos casos a cima são exemplos para simplificar o que desejo fazer.

Qual a forma correta de se trabalhar com snippets no Atom? Segui exemplos da documentação e não consigo os resultados esperados.

Att.
Thiago Prado

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Está faltando um `:` depois do nome do snippet:

```coffee
'.source.php':
  'Controller text':  # Aqui.
    'prefix': 'lco'
    'body': 'my name is $1'
```

Comment: Obrigado, realmente um erro bem bobo de minha parte! Mas acabei não percebendo de forma alguma, mesmo olhando os exemplos, parte ruim de não se ter um debugger.

Comment: Você pode acessar Development Tools a partir do menu View > Developer. Foi assim que eu descobri o que estava errado.

Comment: Aproveitando saberia como fazer para aparecer as opções de uma área de placehold? Estou tentando:

    `'.source.php':
      'laravel route':
      'prefix': 'route'
      'body': 'Route::${1|get,post,resource,any,matched,pattern,filter|}(\'${2:/}\', ${3:function(){\n
        \t${4:...};
      \n}});'`
Mas não da certo, e não tem informações de como fazer corretamente por coffeescript. E também não gera erro.

Answer (score 2):

Nesta versão nova ele simplesmente não estava funcionando.

Para funcionar tive de fazer o seguinte (pra qualquer linguagem) sem necessidade de variáveis.

```all
'*':
  'Snippet Name':
    'prefix': 'html'
    'body': """
      <!DOCTYPE HTML>
      <html lang="pt-br">
          <head>
          $1
          <meta charset="UTF-8">
          <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no">
          <link rel="icon" href="favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon" />
          <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/estilo.css">
          <script type="text/javascript" src="js/arquivoJS.js"></script>
          <title></title>
          </head>
          <body>
            <h1>CONTEUDO</h1>
          </body>
      </html>
    """
```

Answer (score 0):

Segue um exemplo, só não sei como acresentar os icones f: funcão, c: classe etc...

```
'.source.php':
    'Function isset':
        'leftLabel': 'bool'
        'prefix': 'isset($var)'
        'rightLabelHTML': 'Informa se a variável foi iniciada'
        'body': 'isset(${1:$var})$2'
        'description': 'Documentação php.net'
        'descriptionMoreURL': 'https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.isset.php'
```